# How to subset a dataset such that the test set contains

Tags: r

I built a linear regression model (`lm.full`) and I'm trying to test the model on a test data set. I'm running into an issue due to a feature / predictor with many unique values when I try to predict based on the test data. The troublesome feature is cbsa (Core Based Statistical Area).

The train and the test have the same unique values. I'm not sure what the issue is, because if each of the levels of the factor variable is fit in the training model, then I think I should be able to predict the value test.

I divided the data here for the test and training sets:

```
sample.size<-floor(0.95*nrow(tvwm))
# Make sure that seeds different
set.seed(15)
tvwm_train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(tvwm)), size = sample.size)
tvwm_train <- tvwm[tvwm_train_ind,]
tvwm_test <- tvwm[-tvwm_train_ind,]
```

And here is the prediction:

```
> predict(object=lm.full, newdata=tvwm_test, type = "response")

Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor factor(cbsa_name) has new levels Boston-Cambridge-Newton, MA-NH, Detroit-Warren-Livonia, MI, Virginia Beach-Norfolk-Newport News, VA-NC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
all(levels(tvwm_test$cbsa_name) %in% levels(tvwm_train$cbsa_name)) 
all(levels(tvwm_train$cbsa_name) %in% levels(tvwm_test$cbsa_name))
```

and make sure they are both TRUE.  Or, as Gregor suggested below in his comment, you can do it in one statement:

```
identical(levels(tvwm_test$cbsa_name), levels(tvwm_train$cbsa_name))
```

If they are not both TRUE, and you are certain that both the training set and the test set have the same factor levels in the data, then run the following to reset the levels:

```
tvwm_train$cbsa_name <- factor(tvwm_train$cbsa_name)
tvwm_test$cbsa_name <- factor(tvwm_test$cbsa_name)
```

Comment: I think you're missing some parens in your first couple lines. Rather than two statements, you could also use `indentical(levels(tvwm_test$cbsa_name), levels(tvwm_train$cbsa_name))`.

Comment: '> identical(x=levels(tvwm_test), y = levels(tvwm_train))
[1] TRUE'

Comment: Do all of the factor levels have valid observations in both sets?